# Error on passing a Null into Oracle table's NOT NULLABLE column with DATA_DEFAULT set - Entity Framework

Tags: oracle, entity-framework

A column in Oracle DB - table has a `NULLABLE = NO` and `DATA_DEFAULT = 'T'`

Using EntifyFramework, When i'm trying to pass a NULL(this is a string property on the entity where NULL is a default value in it) into this field, i'm expecting it to insert a 'T' into this column but instead it is throwing an error.

```
"The COL_NAME field is required."
```

Answer (score 1):

That is the expected behaviour. The default value is applied when that column is not referenced in the insert statement. When you do reference the column you are overriding the default - whether that is with null or some other not-null value.

[From the documentation for `insert`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/INSERT.html):

> If you omit one or more of the table's columns from this list, then the column value of that column for the inserted row is the column default value as specified when the table was created or last altered. If any omitted column has a NOT NULL constraint and no default value, then the database returns an error indicating that the constraint has been violated and rolls back the `INSERT` statement. Refer to [`CREATE TABLE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/CREATE-TABLE.html#GUID-F9CE0CC3-13AE-4744-A43C-EAC7A71AAAB6) for more information on default column values.

So you have to omit the column to pick up the default.

Default does not mean 'replace null with this'; it means 'use if not set at all'. Set to null is not the same as not set.

Bear in mind that if that wasn't the case, if you had a nullable column with a default value, it would be impossible to explicitly set it to null on insert.

However, you can override that, at least in later versions, as [the `create table` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/CREATE-TABLE.html#GUID-F9CE0CC3-13AE-4744-A43C-EAC7A71AAAB6__GUID-E129E7B9-810E-48B6-A4BF-42547FC47CB2) mentions:

> **DEFAULT**
>
> The `DEFAULT` clause lets you specify a value to be assigned to the column if a subsequent `INSERT` statement omits a value for the column.
> ...
>
> **ON NULL**
>
> If you specify the `ON NULL` clause, then Oracle Database assigns the DEFAULT column value when a subsequent `INSERT` statement attempts to assign a value that evaluates to `NULL`.
>
> When you specify `ON NULL`, the `NOT NULL` constraint and `NOT DEFERRABLE` constraint state are implicitly specified. If you specify an inline constraint that conflicts with `NOT NULL` and `NOT DEFERRABLE`, then an error is raised.

Quick demo:

```
create table t42 (
  id number,
  col_a varchar2(1) default 'A' not null,
  col_b varchar2 (1) default on null 'B'
);

Table T42 created.

insert into t42 (id) values (1);

1 row inserted.

-- this will fail - the scenario from the question
insert into t42 (id, col_a) values (2, null);

ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("STACK"."T42"."COL_A")

insert into t42 (id, col_b) values (3, null);

1 row inserted.

insert into t42 (id, col_a, col_b) values (4, 'X', null);

1 row inserted.

insert into t42 (id, col_a, col_b) values (5, 'Y', 'Z');

1 row inserted.

select * from t42;

        ID C C
---------- - -
         1 A B
         3 A B
         4 X B
         5 Y Z
```

The `on null` clause [was added in 12cR1](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/release_changes.htm#sthref17), so if you're still on an older version you won't be able to use it. But if your on a version that supports it, changing your table definition will allow your explicit null to do what you want.

Comment: I understand the behavior of this.Thank you. I'm confused on how to handle this in Entity Framework.

Comment: It would probably be simplest to change the table definition if you can; otherwise stop EF sending null in the first place. Unfortunately I don't know how to do that, sorry.